# Collectors.groupby for Map<String,List<String>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

Forgive me if the solution is very obvious but I can't seem to figure out how to do this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("b1", "a1");
    map.put("b2", "a2");
    map.put("b3", "a1");
    Map<String, List<String>> mm = map.values().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m -> m));
    System.out.println(mm);
}
```

I want to group by based on values in hashmap. I want the output to be `{a1=[b1, b3], a2=[b2]}` but it is currently coming as `{a1=[a1, a1], a2=[a2]}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently, you're streaming over the map values (which I assume is a typo), based on your required output you should stream over the map `entrySet` and use `groupingBy` based on the map value's and `mapping` as a downstream collector based on the map key's:

```
 Map<String, List<String>> result = map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue,
                          Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                                        Collectors.toList())));
```

You could also perform this logic without a stream via `forEach` + `computeIfAbsent`:

```
Map<String, List<String>> result = new HashMap<>();
map.forEach((k, v) -> result.computeIfAbsent(v, x -> new ArrayList<>()).add(k));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Collectors.mapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) with [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) on the `entrySet` of the map as :

```
Map<String, List<String>> mm = map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, 
                Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())));
```

> but it is currently coming as {a1=[a1, a1], a2=[a2]}

That's because you are currently grouping on the values collection which is  `{a1, a2, a1}` only.

Comment: Read the `collect` as *groupBy value while mapping keys corresponding to them into a `List`*

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> list1 = List.of("Tabu", "Gina", "protijayi", "Gini", "Gini","North Calcutta");
        List<String> list2 = List.of("Soudipta", "Gina", "Gina", "upto");
        List<String> list3 = List.of("Soudipta", "Gina", "protijayi", "Tabu","South Calcutta");
        List<List<String>> listres = List.of(list1, list2, list3);
        System.out.println(listres);
/*
 [[Tabu, Gina, protijayi, Gini, Gini, North Calcutta], 
[Soudipta, Gina, Gina, upto],
 [Soudipta, Gina, protijayi, Tabu, South Calcutta]]

 */



        Map<String, List<Long>> FirstKeyThenValue1 = listres.stream().flatMap(
                // mapper

                list -> list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
                        .entrySet().parallelStream()

        ).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey, Collectors.mapping(
                // mapper, downstream

                Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
        System.out.println("FirstKeyThenValue1  -> " + FirstKeyThenValue1);
        /*
         {
  upto=[1],
   Soudipta=[1, 1],
    Gina=[1, 2, 1], 
    Tabu=[1, 1],
     North Calcutta=[1], 
     South Calcutta=[1], 
     protijayi=[1, 1], 
     Gini=[2]}
         */

        Map<Long, List<String>> FirstValueThenkey1 = listres.stream().flatMap(
                // mapper

                list -> list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
                        .entrySet().stream()

        ).collect(

                Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getValue, Collectors.mapping(


                        Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList()

                ))

        );

        System.out.println(" FirstValueThenkey1 => " + FirstValueThenkey1);

        /*


  {
  1=[Gina, Tabu, North Calcutta, protijayi, upto, Soudipta,
   Soudipta, Gina, Tabu, South Calcutta, protijayi],

 2=[Gini, Gina]
 }
         */





    }// main
}
```