# Invert a Map with redundant values to produce a multimap

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, multimap, multi-mapping

Given a map such as this where we have a frequency count per day-of-week for a year:

```java
Map.of(
    DayOfWeek.MONDAY , 52 ,
    DayOfWeek.TUESDAY , 52 ,
    DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY, 53 ,
    DayOfWeek.THURSDAY , 53 ,
    DayOfWeek.FRIDAY , 52 ,
    DayOfWeek.SATURDAY , 52 ,
    DayOfWeek.SUNDAY , 52 
)
```

…or as text:

> {MONDAY=52, TUESDAY=52, WEDNESDAY=53, THURSDAY=53, FRIDAY=52, SATURDAY=52, SUNDAY=52}

…how can I invert to produce a [multimap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap) of distinct numbers each leading to a collection (list? set?) of the `DayOfWeek` which owned that number?

The result should be equivalent to the result of this code:

```java
Map.of(
    53 , List.of( DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY , DayOfWeek.THURSDAY ) ,
    52 , List.of( DayOfWeek.MONDAY , DayOfWeek.TUESDAY , DayOfWeek.FRIDAY , DayOfWeek.SATURDAY , DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) 
)
```

I would like to produce the resulting [multimap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap) using straight Java without extra libraries such as [*Eclipse Collections*](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) or [*Google Guava*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava). Those libraries might make this easier, but I am curious to see if a solution using only built-in Java is possible. Otherwise, my Question here is the exact same Question as [*Guava: construct a Multimap by inverting a Map*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8157080/642706). Given new streams and multimap features in modern Java, I expect this is possible now while it was not then.

I saw various existing Questions similar to this. But none fit my situation, which seems like a rather common situation. For example, [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7146990/642706) neglects the issue of the original values being redundant/multiple, thus necessitating a multimap as a result. Others such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8157080/642706) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3678601/642706) involve Google Guava.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53986939/collectors-groupby-for-mapstring-liststring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works using Java 9 or above:

```
@Test
void invertMap()
{
    Map<DayOfWeek, Integer> map = Map.of(
            DayOfWeek.MONDAY, 52,
            DayOfWeek.TUESDAY, 52,
            DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY, 53,
            DayOfWeek.THURSDAY, 53,
            DayOfWeek.FRIDAY, 52,
            DayOfWeek.SATURDAY, 52,
            DayOfWeek.SUNDAY, 52
    );

    Map<Integer, Set<DayOfWeek>> flipped = new TreeMap<>();
    map.forEach((dow, count) ->
            flipped.computeIfAbsent(count, (key) ->
                    EnumSet.noneOf(DayOfWeek.class)).add(dow));

    Map<Integer, Set<DayOfWeek>> flippedStream = map.entrySet().stream()
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    Map.Entry::getValue, 
                    TreeMap::new,
                    Collectors.mapping(
                            Map.Entry::getKey,
                            Collectors.toCollection(
                                    () -> EnumSet.noneOf(DayOfWeek.class)))));

    Map<Integer, Set<DayOfWeek>> expected = Map.of(
            53, EnumSet.of(
                    DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY, 
                    DayOfWeek.THURSDAY),
            52, EnumSet.of(
                    DayOfWeek.MONDAY, 
                    DayOfWeek.TUESDAY, 
                    DayOfWeek.FRIDAY, 
                    DayOfWeek.SATURDAY, 
                    DayOfWeek.SUNDAY)
    );
    Assert.assertEquals(expected, flipped);
    Assert.assertEquals(expected, flippedStream);
}
```

If you are open to using a third-party library, the following code will work with [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections):

```
@Test
void invertEclipseCollectionsMap()
{
    MutableMap<DayOfWeek, Integer> map =
            Maps.mutable.<DayOfWeek, Integer>empty()
                    .withKeyValue(DayOfWeek.MONDAY, 52)
                    .withKeyValue(DayOfWeek.TUESDAY, 52)
                    .withKeyValue(DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY, 53)
                    .withKeyValue(DayOfWeek.THURSDAY, 53)
                    .withKeyValue(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY, 52)
                    .withKeyValue(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY, 52)
                    .withKeyValue(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY, 52);

    SetMultimap<Integer, DayOfWeek> flipped = map.flip();

    Assert.assertEquals(flipped.get(52), Set.of(
            DayOfWeek.MONDAY,
            DayOfWeek.TUESDAY,
            DayOfWeek.FRIDAY,
            DayOfWeek.SATURDAY,
            DayOfWeek.SUNDAY));
    Assert.assertEquals(flipped.get(53), Set.of(
            DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY,
            DayOfWeek.THURSDAY));
}
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Comment: Good stuff. Two points: (a) `new TreeMap<>()` works a bit better than `new HashMap<>()` since it puts the numbers (the new keys) in order. (b) Is there a way to use [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumSet.html) rather than `HashSet` since [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) is an enum? The problem is that `EnumSet` class does not offer a constructor. I tried `EnumSet.noneOf` but got error "method noneOf in class EnumSet<E#2> cannot be applied to given types;".

Comment: Good enough, thanks. I was just curious about trying to shoehorn the `EnumSet` factory methods into streams syntax.

Comment: I'm working on a stream example for this, mostly out of my own curiosity now because I know it's possible. I am the creator of the Eclipse Collections framework, which also has methods to flip Map to Multimap built in, so doing this in plain Java code is a good Streams refresher for me.

Comment: I thought your name was familiar. But I didn't recognize you with the mask on. Feel free to append an example of the *Eclipse Collections* solution. I'm not against Google Guava or Eclipse Collections, I was just curious if a bulit-in Java solution is possible.

Comment: I added the Stream version so you can compare. I changed the Map from HashMap to TreeMap and included EnumSet in both solutions. I'll see if I can find some time tomorrow to append an Eclipse Collections solution.

Answer (score 1):

With streams, you can split a map into its entries, then flip the entries and group:

```java
numberOfDaysInYear.entrySet().stream()
  .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue), mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, toList()));
```

Based on your updated comments asking for optimization not actually in your original question,

```java
numberOfDaysInYear.entrySet().stream()
  .collect(groupingBy(
    Map.Entry::getValue,
    TreeMap::new,
    mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, toCollection(() -> EnumSet.of(DayOfWeek.class)))
  ));
```

Comment: Actually, the original Question specifically states that the multimap value could be any collection, list or set. So both your solutions work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## `Collectors.toMap`

In this case you can use method [`Collectors.toMap​(keyMapper,valueMapper,mergeFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) and produce multimap where the value can be a *list* or a *set*:

1. Multimap value is a `List`:

   ```java
   Map<Integer, List<DayOfWeek>> inverted = map.entrySet().stream()
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                   // key of the new map
                   entry -> entry.getValue(),
                   // value of the new map
                   entry -> List.of(entry.getKey()),
                   // merging two values, i.e. lists
                   (list1, list2) -> {
                       List<DayOfWeek> list = new ArrayList<>();
                       list.addAll(list1);
                       list.addAll(list2);
                       return list;
                   }));
   ```
2. Multimap value is a `Set`:

   ```java
   Map<Integer, Set<DayOfWeek>> inverted = map.entrySet().stream()
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                   // key of the new map
                   entry -> entry.getValue(),
                   // value of the new map
                   entry -> Set.of(entry.getKey()),
                   // merging two values, i.e. sets
                   (set1, set2) -> {
                       Set<DayOfWeek> set = new HashSet<>();
                       set.addAll(set1);
                       set.addAll(set2);
                       return set;
                   }));
   ```

---

<sup>See also: [Collect a list of ids based on multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65465627/14838237)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code:

```java
@Test
void testMap() {
    Map<DayOfWeek, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(DayOfWeek.MONDAY, 52);
    map.put(DayOfWeek.TUESDAY, 52);
    map.put(DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY, 53);
    map.put(DayOfWeek.THURSDAY, 53);
    map.put(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY, 52);
    map.put(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY, 52);
    map.put(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY, 52);

    Map<Integer, List<DayOfWeek>> result = new HashMap<>();

    for (Map.Entry<DayOfWeek, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (result.containsKey(entry.getValue())) {
            List list = result.get(entry.getValue());
            list.add(entry.getKey());
            result.put(entry.getValue(), list);
        } else {
            List list = new ArrayList();
            list.add(entry.getKey());
            result.put(entry.getValue(), list);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```